# How to get Replication name of table

Tags: replication, powerdesigner

How can I Get Replication name of table in Package?
for exmaple I Know how can I get table name in event handler

```
Function %Initialize%(obj)
      Output obj.Name  
End Function
```

### Thank you for your help - PD: 16.7.2
David

Resolved:
Obj.SourceReplication